# angularjs watch dynamically generated scope objects

Tags: angularjs, watch

I need to add a watcher dynamically according to a scope property.

The code below work as hard coded, but if I try to get the values from the scope it doesn't work. I've tested multiple times and in this example:

```
$scope.options.hideExpression // "hideDefault"
$scope.options.default_to // "allowed_item_types"



if $scope.options.default_to
  defaultTo = $scope.options.default_to
  $scope.$watch 'model["allowed_item_types"]', (newVal) -> // Hard coded, works
  # $scope.$watch 'model[defaultTo]', (newVal) -> // Dynamically generated from scope, doesn't work
    if Object.count($scope.model[$scope.options.default_to], /true/) == 1 // Dynamically generated from scope, works
      # Set default value
      $scope.model[$scope.options.key] = Object.find(newVal, /true/) // Dynamically generated from scope, works
      # Hide default row
      # $scope[$scope.options.hideExpression] = true // Dynamically generated, doens't work
      $scope["hideDefault"] = true  // Hard coded, works,
    else
      # $scope[$scope.options.hideExpression] = false
      $scope["hideDefault"] = false
  , true
```

Any idea why this is happening?

For some reason this specific line is the only one that works not hard coded:
$scope.model[$scope.options.default_to]